# bar charts with grouped column

Tags: highcharts

I have bar chart as shown below:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ay5z0q4m/1/)

[image]

```js
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Team Comparision'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: [
                'Jan',
                'Feb',
                'Mar',
                'Apr',
                'May',
                'Jun',
                'Jul',
                'Aug',
                'Sep',
                'Oct',
                'Nov',
                'Dec'
            ],
            crosshair: true
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Scores'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
            pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} </b></td></tr>',
            footerFormat: '</table>',
            shared: true,
            useHTML: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                pointPadding: 0.2,
                borderWidth: 0
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Team A',
            data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]

        }, {
            name: 'Team B',
            data: [83.6, 78.8, 98.5, 93.4, 106.0, 84.5, 105.0, 104.3, 91.2, 83.5, 106.6, 92.3]

        }, {
            name: 'Team C',
            data: [48.9, 38.8, 39.3, 41.4, 47.0, 48.3, 59.0, 59.6, 52.4, 65.2, 59.3, 51.2]

        }, {
            name: 'Team D',
            data: [42.4, 33.2, 34.5, 39.7, 52.6, 75.5, 57.4, 60.4, 47.6, 39.1, 46.8, 51.1]

        }]
    });
});
```

Is it possible to have stacked and grouped column with this kind of bar chart in highcharts?

Every team has members. So I would like to display each team member score in their respective team column with members scores stacked in it.

Comment: Yes. Look at the "grouped and stacked" demo from the Highcharts demo page: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-stacked-and-grouped/  You need to use the "stack" property for each series, where each "stack" is one part of the group.

Answer (score 0):

[Updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ay5z0q4m/2/)

The only change is the stacking option in plotoptions.

```
column: {
    stacking: 'normal',
}
```

Comment: I want members score in each team column bar not all the team stacked up in same bar

Comment: So instead of 12 columns with 4 items each, you want 4 columns with 12 items each?

Comment: It will have 12 column and 4 teams for each month. I have members for each team. the team score is the sum of each member score in the team. So i want to stack up individual member score in each team column as well